# IIS How to configure an application has default?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows, iis-7.5

I'm a newbie of windows server and IIS...
After having deployed my asp.net MVC4 application on my IIS Server, I would like to acces to my website by: http://www.website/ and NOT (actualy) http://www.website/Application

Do you know how I can make it on the IIS Server ?

Thanks you all for you help.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just deploy it to the root of your site...

**Using Web Deploy Package**

1. Click on Default Website
2. Import Application
3. Choose package file
4. Click next till you get to **Enter Application Package Information**
5. Delete all text under **Application path** then finish the import

[image: iis import]

You will get a popup saying that most applications are installed in a subfolder. Just choose OK

Comment: In the root directory ? Because when I make that, I have an HTTP 403.14 - Forbidden

Comment: Under Default Web Site. How are you deploying? are you using Web Deploy?

Comment: Yes I'm using Web Deploy Package on VS and I import it the feature "Import an application"

Comment: Even easier! I've updated my question with the steps to follow. Good luck!

Comment: Thnkas you heymega, the problem was the pools applications. It was too old. After .net framework updated, it now work fine ! Thnkas you